# How to make a private variable visible to select classes

Tags: c#, uwp, observablecollection, uwp-xaml

I have two independent classes: YourBooks and NewBook. YourBooks has a private Observable Collection. I want NewBook to be able to update values of the Observable Collection. But YourBooks is a XAML class (inherits Page). And the logic of the program is such that I cannot inherit it. Is there a way of updating my Observable collection?

I feel there is one point I missed and one that you people did. I forgot to mention the fact that NewBook is a ContentDialog. It is guaranteed that NewBook is only initialized from YourBooks. YourBooks is of type Page which creates a custom dialog called NewBook.

Comment: Add a method to the YourBooks class which allows you to modify the private collection.

Comment: You could expose the private field through a public read-only property. But how are accessing YourBooks from NewBook?

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a 'setter'/'getter' for that varaible?
A public method that accesses the private one

```
public void SetObservableCollection(List<Object> value)
{
   ObservableCollection = value;
}

// Or maybe...
public void AddItemToObservableCollection(Object value)
{
   ObservableCollection.add(value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very basic, but I think this should get you going in the right direction:

```
public class temp
{
    private ObservableCollection<int> _myCollection;
    public temp()
    {
        _myCollection = new ObservableCollection<int>();
    }

    public void addInt(int myint)
    {
        _myCollection.Add(myint);
    }
}
```

Then, something like to add to your `ObservableCollection`:

```
var tempthing = new temp();
tempthing.addInt(5);
tempthing.addInt(6);
```

Edit (based on your comment). 
If I understand it correcty, why not pass `YourBooks` to `NewBook`?

```
public class YourBooks
{
    private ObservableCollection<int> _myCollection;
    public YourBooks()
    {
        _myCollection = new ObservableCollection<int>();
        _myCollection.Add(4);
        var newBook = new NewBook(this);
    }

    public void addInt(int myint)
    {
        _myCollection.Add(myint);
    }
}

public class NewBook
{
    public YourBooks YourBooks { get; set; }
    public NewBooks(YourBooks yourBooks)
    {
        YourBooks = yourBooks
        addSomething();
    }

    public void addSomething()
    {
        YourBook.addInt(5);
        YourBook.addInt(6);
    }
}
```